# Why is the expression (0==0 & 1==1) evaluating to False?

Tags: python, operators, operator-precedence

Similarly (-1==-1 & 1==1) is also False.

Apologies if this is something obvious but I can't find an explanation for it.

Comment: use `and` for logical and operation. `&` is used for bit operation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`&` is the **bitwise AND** operator. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), Bitwise operators have higher precedence than logical operators, so

```
0 == 0 & 1 == 1
```

Becomes

```
0 == (0 & 1) == 1
```

And you can imagine it goes downhill from there:

```
   0 == (0 & 1) == 1
=> 0 == 0 == 1
=> 0 == 0 and 0 == 1
=> True and False 
=> False
```

Assuming what you wanted was a **logical AND**, the python way to do that would be using `and`:

```
0 == 0 and 1 == 1
```

Which gives you `True` as you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you! This is the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Lets break this up.

The highest priority sign here is the brackets. Except we're wrapping the entire expression, so they don't do anything.

Next we have the bitwise operator `&`.

`0 & 1` which equals `0`.

This leaves us with `0 == 0 == 1`

As `0` does not equal `1`, we get `False`.

For reference, here is the python documentation about [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: `0 & 1` produces `0`, not `1`... `0 & ANYINTEGER` produces `0`. The end result is similar, but the intermediate step is wrong.

Comment: Oops, must have been thinking of `|`. Thanks :P